# Charts Js and Angular JS not working, Charts not being shown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I am a noob to AngularJs and have never used charts JS before, and am encountering this problem as no charts are being shown. I would appreciate some help. Thank You!

```
<h1 class="text-center">Histogram</h1>

<canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<a ng-click = "vm.edit">Show</a>

angular
.module('histogram-test')
.controller("histoCnt", function ($state, $scope, $rootScope) {
    console.log("Contrller working");
    var vm = this;
    vm.edit = edit;
    $scope.chart = angular.element(document.getElementById("myChart"));

    function edit() {
        var myChart = new Chart($scope.chart, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["M", "T", "W", "R", "F", "S", "S"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'apples',
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 17, 28, 24, 7]
                        }, {
                    label: 'oranges',
                    data: [30, 29, 5, 5, 20, 3, 10]
                        }]
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use angular-charts library . Make sure you inject **`'chart.js'`**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['chart.js'])
```

**DEMO**

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', ['chart.js'])
  .controller('myController', [function() {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.socialChart = {
      options: {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            stacked: true
          }]
        }
      },
      type: 'bar',
      labels: ["M", "T", "W", "R", "F", "S", "S"],
      series: ['apples', 'oranges'],
      colors: ['#ED402A', '#F0AB05', '#A0B421', '#00A39F'],
       data: [
       [12, 19, 3, 17, 28, 24, 7],
       [30, 29, 5, 5, 20, 3, 10]
      ]
    }
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Multi Slot Transclude</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chart.js/1.0.3/angular-chart.min.js"></script>    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
    <canvas id="outreach" class="chart chart-bar" 
        chart-labels="ctrl.socialChart.labels" 
        chart-data="ctrl.socialChart.data" 
        chart-series="ctrl.socialChart.series"
        chart-colors="ctrl.socialChart.colors"
        chart-options="ctrl.socialChart.options"></canvas>      
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: when I add the module, i run into this error - Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module histogram-test due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module chart.js due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'chart.js' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.

Comment: post your code, i have added a demo check it, you need to inject chart.js also add necessary references

Comment: In the same manner can you give some examples for pie charts and line graphs?